# Is there any way to receive a notification when an external user (not G-Suite) changes a Shared Drive content?

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

The goal is to receive a push notification from Google when an external user changes the content of the drive that has been shared with him by a G-Suite (or Google Workspace) account member.
I've already tried the following:

- Watch every user of the G-Suite account with "support all drive" flag setted on true (see [Changes: watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch)):
  In this way the notifications are sent only if the change is triggered by any of the G-Suite users.
- Watch the Shared Drive itself using "[Files: wath](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch)" API:
  In this way the subscription simply fails (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130736018).